# print php if condition result in .html with ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want print if condition true or false result in my html contact form with ajax or any other solution.

```
if($response.success==false) {
        echo '<h2>Your message was not sent. Captcha fail</h2>';}

        else
        {
            $mail = mail(Hanse, $subject, $message,
             "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
            ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
            ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());


            if($mail)
                {
                    echo 'Your message was sent';
                }

        }


}
```

But this code isn't together with my html file. I have contact.html and mail.php files. I want show mail.php process result in contact.html page. In this php code, I can only print results with echo. But I want show this result in my html page.

Comment: Please search on google for AJAX. And implement it. These are very basic things and we cannot teach these here.

Answer (score 1):

Either re-direct or use ajax call.

Change index.html to index.php

in your mail.php, add this:

```
if($mail){
     $message= 'Your message was sent';
     header("location:index.php?message=".$message);
}
```

Add a check in index.php

```
 if(isset($_GET['message'])){
  echo $_GET['message'];
 }
```

Comment: @Ayaz action="contact.php"   your action is contact.php and your code is in mail.php .. kindly look into the tutorials first before moving on to it.